# BackAndroid/BackHandler Event Listeners are not Triggered when set in a Modal's Child Component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am unable to set event listeners using the react-native **BackHandler** in a component that is placed inside a modal. I suspect that this happens because the modal is listening to the method that is passed on the **onRequestClose** prop.

Well, I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature request but I would suggest that you allowed us to pass a certain value (e.g null) to the **onRequestClose** prop as a way of flagging that there might be BackHandler event listeners being set in the Modal's child components, and that these listeners have priority (i.e override the **onRequestClose** of the Modal).

### Environment

Environment:

- OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
- Node: 9.2.0
- Yarn: 0.24.6
- npm: 5.6.0
- Watchman: 4.7.0
- Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
- Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4408382

Packages: (wanted => installed)

- react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
- react-native: 0.53.0

  => 0.53.0

### Steps to Reproduce

Below there is the instructions  inside the child component:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBackPress)
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBackPress)
    }

    _onBackPress = () => {
        console.log('Event was triggered')

        return true
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Text>{'Some Text'}</Text>
        )
    }
}

export default ChildComponent
```

The component that has the Modal (parent) has the following instructions:

```
class ParentComponentWithModal extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            modalVisible: true
        }
    }

    render () {
        const { modalVisible } = this.state
        return (
            <View>
                <Modal
                    visible={modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => console.log('onRequestClose')}
            >
                <ChildComponent />
            </Modal>
          </View>
        )
    }
}

export default ParentComponentWithModal
```

### Expected Behavior

The **_onBackPress** method added to hardwareBackPressed listener should be executed when the back button is pressed.

### Actual Behavior

When the back button is pressed, the function defined on the **onRequestClose** prop is triggered. Even if no function is defined on the **onRequestClose** prop, the methods attached to the event listeners defined in the modal's children are not executed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This behaviour is documented on [React Native's site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal#onrequestclose):

> onRequestClose
>   The onRequestClose callback is called when the user taps the hardware back button on
>   Android or the menu button on Apple TV. Because of this required prop, be aware that
>   BackHandler events will not be emitted as long as the modal is open.

So you will need to use the **onRequestClose** function instead of BackHandler.

```
<Modal
   visible={visible}
   onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ visible: false })}
>
```

Comment: YES!, if you're trying to handle back press while modal opened, you should use onRequestClose callback of modal. Thanks, you saved my day.